# Deactivating hashlinks rewrite in silverstripe 3.1

Tags: silverstripe

The old way of doing this is deprected.  Is there a new way to do this? What are the pros and cons?

```
SSViewer:: dontRewriteHashlinks();
```

The requirement is because it breaks many JS plugins.  Altering those standard UI components instead of making this change to SS seems the wrong way to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in `/mysite/_config.php`

`Config::inst()->update('SSViewer', 'rewrite_hash_links', false);`

or using the YAML config system (ex. `/mysite/_config/config.yml`)

```
SSViewer:
  rewrite_hash_links: false
```

See http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/3.1/reference/templates#fragment-link-rewriting

Comment: Just a note: the YAML config version is preferred, as it allows the config value to be cached.

Comment: wow thats faster! each item i remove from _config.php is nocking off 50ms from the page process time. it started at 950ms so awesome to be making some inroads there.

Comment: That link is now broken. Try http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/templates/how_tos/disable_anchor_links/